# How to read a pickle file containing a sparse matrix of of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>' in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to read a pickle file in Julia which is originally created in python. Here is what I did:

```
f3=open("filename.pickle");

r3 = pickle.load(f3)
```

This returns the following:

```
PyObject <41302x1425 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 1602890 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

1. How can I access the matrix elements?
2. Assuming that I have a sparse matrix in Julia, how can I store the data into a pickle file with the same format?

Just FYI, I already did the following to resolve an error regarding not finding scipy module:

```
using Conda

Conda.add("scipy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Julia to Python pickle:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> a = rand(Float32, 2,2)
2×2 Array{Float32,2}:
 0.943764  0.726961
 0.9184    0.422781

julia> pickle = pyimport("pickle");

julia> open("pyt.pickle", "w") do f
         pickle.dump(a, f)
       end
```

Reading the above pickle in Python:

```
>>> import pickle, numpy
>>> f=open("pyt.pickle","rb")
>>> a = pickle.load(f)
>>> f.close()
>>> a
array([[0.94376445, 0.72696066],
       [0.91840017, 0.42278147]], dtype=float32)
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Preparing a new pickle that will be read this time in Julia:

```
>>> b = numpy.ones((2,3),dtype='float32')
>>> b
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
>>> f=open("pyt2.pickle","wb")
>>> pickle.dump(b, f)
>>> f.close()
```

Reading the Python created pickle in Julia:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> pickle = pyimport("pickle");

julia> open("pyt2.pickle", "r") do f
         pickle.load(f)
       end
2×3 Array{Float32,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0
```

After this intro let's do a sparse array. We start with a Python setup:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> a = scipy.sparse.rand(4,4,0.25,dtype="float32")
>>> a
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
        with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
>>> f=open("pyt3.pickle","wb")
>>> pickle.dump(a, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> print(a)
  (0, 3)        0.30552787
  (3, 0)        0.810103
  (2, 1)        0.691249
  (2, 2)        0.63436085
```

Let us now read it in Julia:

```
julia> a=open("pyt3.pickle", "r") do f
                pickle.load(f)
                       end
PyObject <4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
julia> using SparseArrays;      
julia> res = spzeros(Float32, a.shape...);
julia> sp = pyimport("scipy.sparse");
julia> i,j,vals = sp.find(a);

julia> setindex!.(Ref(res), vals, i .+ 1, j .+ 1); #we copy the data to Julia structure


julia> res
4×4 SparseMatrixCSC{Float32,Int64} with 4 stored entries:
  [4, 1]  =  0.810103
  [3, 2]  =  0.691249
  [3, 3]  =  0.634361
  [1, 4]  =  0.305528
```